# .net draw different images using a bitmap

Tags: .net, bitmap, managed-c++, drawimage

I have a function, It takes a parameter and decides which image to be drawn.
It creates a Bitmap; and draws it.
I called this function four times but it creates the same image all the time.
I think the reason is Bitmap^(pointer).

How can I fix this?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
System::Void CreateCellImage( Exp^ e1)
{
Bitmap^  cell_image = gcnew Bitmap(50,50);
Graphics^ s = Graphics::FormImage(cell_image);
for( int i = 0; i < e1->size; i++ )
s->drawImage(my_icon, e1->Item[i]->x, e1->Item[i]->y);
this->picBox[i]->Image = cell_image;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I draw the same bitmap all the time, It is my fault.